Delete entry from the spreadsheet and move the particular data field to other spreadsheet
I have 2 spreasheets in excel file where I enter the daily objects to be completed in spreadsheet 1 and master data in spreadsheet 2 ( where the the objects which are completed are stored )
As of now, I manually delete the entries from spreadsheet 1 and save those entries in master data i.e. spreadsheet 2 ( cut and paste )
Is there any way so that I can automate this process if I add a new column and update "Completed" and then the entry gets removed from spreadsheet 1 and moved to spreadsheet 2.
I have attached the desired output screenshots below:
Sheet 1 ( daily objects to be completed ):

Master Data ( where the completed objects are saved and then deleted from spreadsheet 1 )

After this, the updated Sheet 1 should look like this:

Thank you everyone in advance.

This code moves the complete rows marked as Completed from Sheet1 to Master Sheet. Does the task for reversed rows to avoid numbering conflicts when deletion occurs.
Sub move_rows()

Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet, targetsheet As Worksheet
Set sourcesheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set targetsheet = Worksheets("Master Sheet")

lastrow = sourcesheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
targetrow = targetsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
If targetrow = 1048577 Then targetrow = 1
For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
  If sourcesheet.Cells(i, 3) = "Completed" Then
    sourcesheet.Rows(i).Copy targetsheet.Rows(targetrow)
    targetsheet.Rows(targetrow).Insert
    sourcesheet.Rows(i).Delete
  End If
  
Next i
targetsheet.Rows(targetrow).Delete
End Sub


